# Print "=>" in text with Qt's implementation of XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, qt, xslt

I am really driving crazy trying to transform an XML file with Qt-XSLT.

My output is pure text, and I want to generate a line like:

`A => B`

I found no way to prevent Qt from transforming the `>` character into 
`&gt;`.

I have of course tried with "disable-output-escaping" but it is not supported (I get an error "Attribute disable-output-escaping cannot appear on the element text. Only the standard attributes can appear."). It is not a valid attribute for a "value-of" node either, and using a character map did not work too (I obtain an error "The element with local name character-map does not exist in XSL-T.").

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks a lot in advance!

R

Comment: Did you tried A =\> B ?

Comment: \ is not a valid escape sequence (I've tried anyway but no luck :S). Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you get text out of it, one option might be to simply do search-replace in the text after the transformation.

Comment: Thanks hyde, I was typing the answer at the very same time! :)

Comment: Have you used `<xsl:output method="text"/>`?

Comment: Yes, I use it (I've also tried with xml output, to check whether it was a text-related problem, but no luck)

Comment: According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/xmlprocessing.html#xslt-2-0 `xsl:output` is indeed "not supported", given the list there of not supported features the warning  "XSLT support is considered experimental" is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

After hours wasted on a "clean" solution, I went the "dirty" way:

the solution is simply to let Qt do its job (replacing all the `>` with `&gt;`) and then do a post-processing by invoking `QString::replace()`.